# Submit a form from a Modal in Vue js

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, modal-dialog

I need to send a form from a modal. Not using a full Vue app, but inserting Vue.js in my HTML page.

- I tried a lot of unsuccesful things with my current modal, so I reduced it to the basic modal example I used for the first time https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html
- For the form, I used also the most basic form validation example at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html (I have it working in other places).
- And I have created this unsuccessful fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/JIBRVI/03qnok9m/53/

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template'
})
// start app
// eslint-disable-next-line no-new
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showModal: false,
    errors: [],
    name: ''
  },
  methods: {
    checkForm: function (e) {
      if (this.name) {
        return true
      }
      this.errors = []
      if (!this.name) {
        this.errors.push('Name required.')
      }
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }

})
```

In the basic modal example I added the form with a field, a submit button and a placeholder to show errors. Also the input field «name» and the array «errors» to the data section in the app. I also added the «checkForm» method.

The main error says:

> Property or method &quot;checkForm&quot; is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property

Maybe the main page can communicate with the modal, so data and methods from the main page can’t be used.

I also tried to make a component with the form, but it didn’t work either. I can’t communicate with the modal.

Any help will be aprreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `name` and `checkform` methods to the `modal` component. You have currently defined those two in the `app` component and are trying to access it from the modal which is in the `modal` component.

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
  data(){
    return {
        name: '',
        errors: [],
    }
  
  },
  methods: {
    checkForm: function (e) {
      if (this.name) {
        return true
      }

      this.errors = []

      if (!this.name) {
        this.errors.push('Name required.')
      }

      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: So everything MUST BE in the component. My wrong approach was trying to communicate the app whith the component maintaining all the logic in the app. Thanks.